# scala implicit return value issue

Tags: scala

Using Scala "2.10.4", I have a implicit definition like this:

```
implicit class MyImplicits(val s: S) {
  def ==>(relation: W):Option[List[S]] = {
    getRelation(s,relation)
  }
}
```

when I want to use it, following works fine:

```
import MyImplicits
val list1 = s ==>(w)
val value = list1.get
```

But when I write this I get error:

```
import MyImplicits
val value = s ==>(w).get


Error:(56, 67) value get is not a member of MyImplicits
      val value = s ==>(w).get
                            ^
```

What is the reason for this error and is there anyway to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because it applies `get` to `(w)` rather than to the whole expression.

Try this:

```
val value = (s ==>(w)).get
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working in this way but what is the difference here with a simple method?

Comment: The difference is that dot operator has higher precedence than `==>` operator, so it was applied first.

Answer (score 0):

As Ashalynd already explained, the period has a higher precedence than the ==> operator. You can get around it with parenthesis or you could use the `get` as an postfix operator:

```
val value = s ==> w get
```